# Find all combinations by columns

Tags: combinatorics

I have n-raws m-columns matrix and want to find all combinations. For example:

```
2 5 6 9
5 2 8 3
1 1 9 4
2 5 3 9
```

my program will print

```
2-5-6-9
2-5-6-3
2-5-6-4
2-5-6-9
2-5-8-9
2-5-8-3...
```

Can't define m x `for` loops. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursion. It is enough to specify for each position which values can be there (columns), and make a recursion which has as parameters list of numbers for passed positions. In recursion iteration make iteration through possibilities of next position.

Python implementation:

```
def C(choose_numbers, possibilities):
  if len(choose_numbers) >= len(possibilities):
    print '-'.join(map(str, choose_numbers))  # format output
  else:
    for i in possibilities[len(choose_numbers)]:
      C(choose_numbers+[i], possibilities)

c = [[2, 5, 1, 2], [5, 2, 1, 5], [6, 8, 9, 3], [9, 3, 4, 9]]
C([], c)
```